# Typescript: conditional typecheck with instanceof not working as expected

Tags: typescript

```
export const initPeer = (t: Chat | Diagnostic, test?: boolean) => {

  // bleep bloop ... code here

  if (test && t instanceof Diagnostic) {
    setupPeerTest(t, p);
  } else if (t instanceof Chat) {
    setupPeer(t, p);
  }
};
```

this code gives me the TSError. I would have thought that I already forced them to be of one type or another...

```
src/components/Chat/peer.ts:139:19 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Chat | Diagnostic' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Diagnostic'.
  Type 'Chat' is missing the following properties from type 'Diagnostic': defaultState, browsers, append, isPassed

139     setupPeerTest(t, p);
                      ~

src/components/Chat/peer.ts:141:15 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Chat | Diagnostic' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chat'.
  Type 'Diagnostic' is missing the following properties from type 'Chat': tickTimer, tabDiv, adapter, default, and 28 more.

141     setupPeer(t, p);
                  ~
```

Comment: I wonder if it's something else before all this, and then this is a side-effect? Because [I can't replicate it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20A)%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20bar(b%3A%20B)%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20baz(x%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%2C%20test%3F%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(test%20%26%26%20x%20instanceof%20A)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo(x)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(x%20instanceof%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bar(x)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) in the TypeScript playground. Can you update your question w/an MCVE?

Comment: what version of TS are you on? `instanceof` should act as a typeguard

Comment: Please post your definitions for your classes. *Might* have something to do with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7271) though it's a bit different...

Comment: they do have a very similar structure so I think that link is the problem. I will post a full example if I can get some time

Answer (score 2):

> I would have thought that I already forced them to be of one type or another...

I don't think TypeScript evaluates your logic to that degree. I think you'll need type assertions:

```
if (test && t instanceof Diagnostic) {
  setupPeerTest(<Diagnostic>t, p);
// -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
} else if (t instanceof Chat) {
  setupPeer(<Chat>t, p);
// ---------^^^^^^
}
```

Or

```
if (test && t instanceof Diagnostic) {
  setupPeerTest(t as Diagnostic, p);
// --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} else if (t instanceof Chat) {
  setupPeer(t as Chat, p);
// ----------^^^^^^^^
}
```

Perhaps without the `test` variable in there it might be able to infer it, but...

Comment: it works, the weird part though is that the compiler never gave me errors until just now so it must have been something that changed in a more recent update of typescript?

Comment: ...except [I can't replicate that](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20A)%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20bar(b%3A%20B)%20%7B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20baz(x%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%2C%20test%3F%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(test%20%26%26%20x%20instanceof%20A)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo(x)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(x%20instanceof%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bar(x)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) in the PlayGround (including with the flag), so this may be incorrect. If I set up your situation, I don't get an error from TS.